# Android navigation drawer doesn't show listview. Just blank

Tags: android, listview, android-navigation, android-drawer

I'm currently trying to add a navigation drawer to all my activities. I can see the navigation drawer when I swipe from the edge of the screen but there's nothing in it a black background here is my code for the DrawerActivity

```
public class DrawerActivity extends Activity {
public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
public FrameLayout frameLayout;
public String[] mDrawerItems;
public ListView drawerList;

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_n_activity, null);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_frame);
    drawerList = (ListView) drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);
    super.setContentView(drawerLayout);

    mDrawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.NAV_MENU_ITEMS);
    drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerItems));
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_drawer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

}

and the drawer_n_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
          android:layout_width="240dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
          android:dividerHeight="0dp"
          android:background="#111"/>
```

EDIT:
and the activitydrawer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

What could I be doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: why do you have so many layouts? what is activity_drawer, and why is your drawer layout seperate from your activity layout and then inflated in?

Comment: just made an edit. The activity_drawer is the name of the xml file created with drawer activity. The reason I have 2 xml files is because that is the way it was done in a tutorial which i seem to have lost the link to.

Comment: are you sure that you have elements inside R.array.NAV_MENU_ITEMS?

Comment: Yes there are elements in the array. I have even tried using a java string array rather the the xml elements and I got the same blank drawer

Comment: I just realized what the problem was. I have posted the answer below. Thanks for all your responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized what the problem was. I had the listview background set to #111 which is opaque black and of course the text was also black so couldn't be seen. I have set the background to #fff (white) and it works fine now.